# Relation between contours of $\phi$ and $f$ if $\nabla^2\phi=f$

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

Given Poisson equation $\nabla^2\phi=f$, what's the relation between the contours of $\phi$ and $f$. Or are there any at all?

In fact, let $\vec n = \nabla\phi$, we have $\nabla\cdot\vec n=f$. $\vec n$ is a direction field with divergence given by $f$, and the gradient of $f$ is also a vector field. So an equivalent question is what's the relation between the two vector fields.

I am not a PDE theoretician, is there any good material that goes deeper into the *geometric* interpretation of PDE, including simple ones like Poisson and Helmholtz equations?

Comment: I doubt it, at least in two dimensions, given that the real part of a holomorphic function can have arbitrarily complicated contours, while $f=0$ doesn't (and one could probably make a more sophisticated argument involving adding a harmonic function).

Comment: @Chappers Thank you for your comment, not mathematician by training, I don't really know what holomorphic is. Maybe I am expecting too much. In 1D of course all the functions' "contour" are parallel to each other. So it's a bit disappointing that in 2D no such "good" relation exists.